# AddTextBox in PowerPoint

Tags: powerpoint, shapes

Assuming slideShape is a reference to a Shapes object, to create a text box in a PPT slide, I can use the following code:

```
slideShape.AddTextBox(Orientation, left, top, width, height)
slideShape.AddTextBox.Text = 'ABC-123 Feb 2015 Mike Smith'
```

So far so good.  But if I want to break the text in 3 lines:

```
ABC-123 
Feb 2015 
Mike Smith
```

and I need to color, re-size, and apply a different font style to each line, I could write three separate `slideShape.AddTextBox` calls, but doing that will create 3 separate text boxes.

Is it possible to write 3 separate lines in *one* text box?  I don't think AddTextBox allow me to do that.  I know it can be done by using some other methods, but I'm not sure how.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub Thing()

    ' Some setup to add a text box
    Dim oSl As Slide
    Dim oSh As Shape

    Set oSl = ActivePresentation.Slides(1)
    Set oSh = oSl.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 0, 0, 500, 500)

    ' But add the tex like so ... with a CR/LF pair at the end of every line:
    oSh.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "ABC-123" & vbCrLf & "Feb 2015" & vbCrLf & "Mike Smith"

    ' The shape's TextRange has a .Paragraphs collection that you can address
    ' a paragraph at a time.
    ' Note: there's also a .Lines collection
    With oSh.TextFrame.TextRange
        .Paragraphs(1).Font.Color.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        .Paragraphs(2).Font.Color.RGB = RGB(0, 255, 0)
        .Paragraphs(3).Font.Color.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 255)
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much for you information. And I wonder if  it's possible to set single space between each paragraph

Comment: It works great.  Thank you so much.  I wonder if there is any online sources and book to teach how to code native PPT with examples

Comment: Steve,  thank you so much for helping me with codes.  Your codes is my life saver.  It took me a day to try it.  How do I do if ABC-123 and Feb 2015 are on the same line, but I need to make Feb 2015 looks (color, size, etc.) from ABC-123?

Comment: I am Coldfusion developer,  sometimes my users want to convert some html pages into native PPT, I never have coded the native PPT before, and the syntext of native PPT is slightly different to embed into ColdFusion, for example CF will not understand vbCrLf but it does chr(13).  Beside http://www.pptfaq.com/index.html,  you know if there is online sources out there with examples/codes that I can learn from.  Again MANY thanks

Comment: Correction: it took me a day to try it before I got your codes.  It took me about 15 minutes with your codes to make it works :-)

Comment: It's always a good idea to mention the language you're working with so that adjustments can be made.  VBCRLF is a Visual Basic constant = Carriage Return + Linefeed pair.  For more sources of information, scroll down to the beginning of the Programming section of pptfaq.com ; there's a list of other sites with good information.

Answer (score 0):

With oSh.TextFrame.TextRange
    .ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter = 12
End With

.SpaceAfter is specified in points, as is the text size